# Forcing OpenGL Core Profile Only

Tags: opengl

Is there a compiler flag or another way of forcing OpenGL core profile only? I want to get an error when i use deprecated functions like glRotatef and so on.

EDIT1: I am using Linux, however, i am also interested in knowing how to do this in Windows

EDIT2: I would prefer to get an error at compile time, but runtime error would be ok as well.

Comment: What platform are you on? The answer to your question depends on what you use to link to OpenGL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could compile your code using `gl3.h` instead of `gl.h`.

http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl3.h

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. By that i mean i get no error when i compile using deprecated non core profile functions. I think the reason is that i also include glx.h and it in turn includes gl.h.

Comment: Stupid trick you perhaps have already tried: trying emitting __#define __gl_h____ before including glx.h to 'prevent' gl.h from being included ?

Comment: Headers make no difference on the version of OpenGL context created. They are only, well, headers.

Comment: The point is that if you include a header that declares GL3 core functions only, you can spot 'non-core' functions in your code _at compile time_, and not at runtime. This has indeed nothing to do with the created GL context.

Comment: But you can't distinguish various OpenGL 3 versions in that way I think. If an application would want to use one of several versions (i.e. try 3.3 forward compatible, if fail fallback to 3.1, if fail fallback to 3.0) then this method wouldn't help. It's still nice to have as few defs as possible for code assist, though.

Comment: Sure, but my point is only valid in the context of this question, where I understand that the OP wants to remove deprecated function calls from an existing codebase. I totally agree with you in a more general context of runtime compatbility.

Comment: Ok i got this working by copying glx.h to my local directory and commenting out the place where gl.h is being included, and then including gl3.h in my own code. I am however still interested in knowing if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Note that it has been renamed to glcorearb.h, for anyone wondering why they can't it any more.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this is both one of the most high-voted answers and the one accepted as correct.  Including a particular header file has absolutely *zero* effect on the type of context that is requested.  You have to request a minimum version from GLX, WGL, GLFW, SDL, or whatever you use to manage your OpenGL context, and you will get a core profile, which will raise errors when you use deprecated functions.

Comment: @rdb as stated above, this answer is related to the question, that prefers compile-time errors vs. runtime errors.

Comment: Fair enough, although that is not nearly enough to catch the majority of non-core functionality use.

Answer (score 8):

Try [wglCreateContextAttribsARB()](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt) with `WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`.

Or [glXCreateContextAttribsARB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt) with `GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`.

You might find [this example](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_%28GLX%29) useful as a testbed.

Comment: This is for windows only, no? Unfortunately i dont have access to a windows machine at the moment so i can not try this out.

Comment: This does not seem to force OpenGL core profile only. I changed the testbed to include GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB and included a glRotatef call after the first "sleep(1);" call and i get no errors.

Comment: This doesn't help because the core profile bit is actually *the default*.  It takes no effect as long as you don't request a minimum OpenGL version as well, which can also be set with the same function.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what creates your OpenGL context.

If you're using GLFW (which I sincerely recommend for standalone OGL window apps), then you can do before you create the window:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR,1);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// the last line shouldn't be necessary
// as you request a specific GL context version - 
// - at least my ATI will then default to core profile
```

Note that if you request a pre-3.0 GL context on modern hardware/drivers, you're likely to receive a newest possible context in compatibility mode instead. Check what your GPU returns from `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` to make sure.

If you use another API for creation of OpenGL context, check its reference manual for similar functions.

---

BTW:
I believe it's impossible to get an error in compile time - your compiler can't be aware what OpenGL context you will receive after your request (if any). The correct way of ensuring that you're not using out-of-version functionality is testing for `glGetError()`.

Also, I recommend using the `gl3w` extension wrapper if you compile for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do it using the Unofficial OpenGL Software Development Kit:

http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html

By using the 'GL Load' component its possible to load a core profile of OpenGL and to remove compatibility enums and functions for versions of OpenGL 3.1 or greater. A short howto can be found here:

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#Unofficial_OpenGL_SDK