# OpenGL 4 adoption

Tags: opengl, graphics, specifications

Having only recently started learning the 'new' OpenGL (programmable as opposed to fixed-function, I learned from the Nehe Tutorials), I'm wondering if learning OpenGL 3 is at all useful since OpenGL 4 was released.

The reason I ask is because I'm wondering as to the number of machines able to use OpenGL 4.

Is it widely adopted currently, do most graphics cards support it?  Is OpenGL 4 even radically different from OpenGL 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL 4 is not radically different from OpenGL 3. It supports binary shaders and 64-bit data types and some other things, but nothing that makes your OpenGL 3 apps immediately obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

As above, but if you want to learn the modern way to use OpenGL, I recommend you only use the core profile, and not the deprecated bits (fixed func...). You can either [make the GL fail on calling obsolete functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693017/forcing-opengl-core-profile-only), or run your app through gDEBugger (free) which will give you warnings.