# Can I explicitly disable deprecated OpenGL functions in my code?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I recently started writing code that uses newer implementations of OpenGL. I did however notice, than in newer OpenGL implementations a lof of old functions are considered as deprecated. Is there any way to disable them if I only want to use proper functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ARB_create_context_profile](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt) and request a forward-compatible context.

> Forward-compatible contexts are defined only for OpenGL
>   versions 3.0 and later. They must not support functionality marked
>   as deprecated by that version of the API, while a
>   non-forward-compatible context must support all functionality in
>   that version, deprecated or not.

Comment: Ok, i guess black screen means it worked. Is there any way to get info about the called functions that don't work or they just don't work?

Comment: The functions are not supported/implemented, so a correct implementation should return `nullptr` on `GetProcAddress` for all post-1.2 functions and either a crash or fail silently for the statically linked pre-1.2 functions (personally, I prefer "crash", but most implementors will probably fail silently, i.e. "black screen"). In theory, a debug context should give you more detailled information like this (e.g. invoke a callback for each unimplemented func), but they don't seem to work (not for me on my nvidia card, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You could compile using http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl3.h as suggested here:
[Forcing OpenGL Core Profile Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693017/forcing-opengl-core-profile-only)